# Simplify code using do until vb6

Tags: vb6

I'm doing a program in VB6 that simulates the process of multiplying a 6x6 to 6x6 matrix. I just did the code only for the first row and second row. To be frankly honest I'm a beginner in programming so I'm still figuring things out.

Can someone show how to simplify this code using do until loop so that I can also apply it for the remaining 3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th row?

Re:
I also added the code for rows 3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th. Pls do help me.

```
an(0).Text = Val(a(0).Text) * Val(b(0).Text) + Val(a(1).Text) * Val(b(6).Text) + Val(a(2).Text) * Val(b(12).Text) + Val(a(3).Text) * Val(b(18).Text) + Val(a(4).Text) * Val(b(24).Text) + Val(a(5).Text) * Val(b(30).Text)
an(1).Text = Val(a(0).Text) * Val(b(1).Text) + Val(a(1).Text) * Val(b(7).Text) + Val(a(2).Text) * Val(b(13).Text) + Val(a(3).Text) * Val(b(19).Text) + Val(a(4).Text) * Val(b(25).Text) + Val(a(5).Text) * Val(b(31).Text)
an(2).Text = Val(a(0).Text) * Val(b(2).Text) + Val(a(1).Text) * Val(b(8).Text) + Val(a(2).Text) * Val(b(14).Text) + Val(a(3).Text) * Val(b(20).Text) + Val(a(4).Text) * Val(b(26).Text) + Val(a(5).Text) * Val(b(32).Text)
an(3).Text = Val(a(0).Text) * Val(b(3).Text) + Val(a(1).Text) * Val(b(9).Text) + Val(a(2).Text) * Val(b(15).Text) + Val(a(3).Text) * Val(b(21).Text) + Val(a(4).Text) * Val(b(27).Text) + Val(a(5).Text) * Val(b(33).Text)
an(4).Text = Val(a(0).Text) * Val(b(4).Text) + Val(a(1).Text) * Val(b(10).Text) + Val(a(2).Text) * Val(b(16).Text) + Val(a(3).Text) * Val(b(22).Text) + Val(a(4).Text) * Val(b(28).Text) + Val(a(5).Text) * Val(b(34).Text)
an(5).Text = Val(a(0).Text) * Val(b(5).Text) + Val(a(1).Text) * Val(b(11).Text) + Val(a(2).Text) * Val(b(17).Text) + Val(a(3).Text) * Val(b(23).Text) + Val(a(4).Text) * Val(b(29).Text) + Val(a(5).Text) * Val(b(35).Text)
an(6).Text = Val(a(6).Text) * Val(b(0).Text) + Val(a(7).Text) * Val(b(6).Text) + Val(a(8).Text) * Val(b(12).Text) + Val(a(9).Text) * Val(b(18).Text) + Val(a(10).Text) * Val(b(24).Text) + Val(a(11).Text) * Val(b(30).Text)
an(7).Text = Val(a(6).Text) * Val(b(1).Text) + Val(a(7).Text) * Val(b(7).Text) + Val(a(8).Text) * Val(b(13).Text) + Val(a(9).Text) * Val(b(19).Text) + Val(a(10).Text) * Val(b(25).Text) + Val(a(11).Text) * Val(b(31).Text)
an(8).Text = Val(a(6).Text) * Val(b(2).Text) + Val(a(7).Text) * Val(b(8).Text) + Val(a(8).Text) * Val(b(14).Text) + Val(a(9).Text) * Val(b(20).Text) + Val(a(10).Text) * Val(b(26).Text) + Val(a(11).Text) * Val(b(32).Text)
an(9).Text = Val(a(6).Text) * Val(b(3).Text) + Val(a(7).Text) * Val(b(9).Text) + Val(a(8).Text) * Val(b(15).Text) + Val(a(9).Text) * Val(b(21).Text) + Val(a(10).Text) * Val(b(27).Text) + Val(a(11).Text) * Val(b(33).Text)
an(10).Text = Val(a(6).Text) * Val(b(4).Text) + Val(a(7).Text) * Val(b(10).Text) + Val(a(8).Text) * Val(b(16).Text) + Val(a(9).Text) * Val(b(22).Text) + Val(a(10).Text) * Val(b(28).Text) + Val(a(11).Text) * Val(b(34).Text)
an(11).Text = Val(a(6).Text) * Val(b(5).Text) + Val(a(7).Text) * Val(b(11).Text) + Val(a(8).Text) * Val(b(17).Text) + Val(a(9).Text) * Val(b(23).Text) + Val(a(10).Text) * Val(b(29).Text) + Val(a(11).Text) * Val(b(35).Text)

an(12).Text = Val(A(12).Text) * Val(B(0).Text) + Val(A(13).Text) * Val(B(6).Text) + Val(A(14).Text) * Val(B(12).Text) + Val(A(15).Text) * Val(B(18).Text) + Val(A(16).Text) * Val(B(24).Text) + Val(A(17).Text) * Val(B(30).Text)
an(13).Text = Val(A(12).Text) * Val(B(1).Text) + Val(A(13).Text) * Val(B(7).Text) + Val(A(14).Text) * Val(B(13).Text) + Val(A(15).Text) * Val(B(19).Text) + Val(A(16).Text) * Val(B(25).Text) + Val(A(17).Text) * Val(B(31).Text)
an(14).Text = Val(A(12).Text) * Val(B(2).Text) + Val(A(13).Text) * Val(B(8).Text) + Val(A(14).Text) * Val(B(14).Text) + Val(A(15).Text) * Val(B(20).Text) + Val(A(16).Text) * Val(B(26).Text) + Val(A(17).Text) * Val(B(32).Text)
an(15).Text = Val(A(12).Text) * Val(B(3).Text) + Val(A(13).Text) * Val(B(9).Text) + Val(A(14).Text) * Val(B(15).Text) + Val(A(15).Text) * Val(B(21).Text) + Val(A(16).Text) * Val(B(27).Text) + Val(A(17).Text) * Val(B(33).Text)
an(16).Text = Val(A(12).Text) * Val(B(4).Text) + Val(A(13).Text) * Val(B(10).Text) + Val(A(14).Text) * Val(B(16).Text) + Val(A(15).Text) * Val(B(22).Text) + Val(A(16).Text) * Val(B(28).Text) + Val(A(17).Text) * Val(B(34).Text)
an(17).Text = Val(A(12).Text) * Val(B(5).Text) + Val(A(13).Text) * Val(B(11).Text) + Val(A(14).Text) * Val(B(17).Text) + Val(A(15).Text) * Val(B(23).Text) + Val(A(16).Text) * Val(B(29).Text) + Val(A(17).Text) * Val(B(35).Text)

an(18).Text = Val(A(18).Text) * Val(B(0).Text) + Val(A(19).Text) * Val(B(6).Text) + Val(A(20).Text) * Val(B(12).Text) + Val(A(21).Text) * Val(B(18).Text) + Val(A(22).Text) * Val(B(24).Text) + Val(A(23).Text) * Val(B(30).Text)
an(19).Text = Val(A(18).Text) * Val(B(1).Text) + Val(A(19).Text) * Val(B(7).Text) + Val(A(20).Text) * Val(B(13).Text) + Val(A(21).Text) * Val(B(19).Text) + Val(A(22).Text) * Val(B(25).Text) + Val(A(23).Text) * Val(B(31).Text)
an(20).Text = Val(A(18).Text) * Val(B(2).Text) + Val(A(19).Text) * Val(B(8).Text) + Val(A(20).Text) * Val(B(14).Text) + Val(A(21).Text) * Val(B(20).Text) + Val(A(22).Text) * Val(B(26).Text) + Val(A(23).Text) * Val(B(32).Text)
an(21).Text = Val(A(18).Text) * Val(B(3).Text) + Val(A(19).Text) * Val(B(9).Text) + Val(A(20).Text) * Val(B(15).Text) + Val(A(21).Text) * Val(B(21).Text) + Val(A(22).Text) * Val(B(27).Text) + Val(A(23).Text) * Val(B(33).Text)
an(22).Text = Val(A(18).Text) * Val(B(4).Text) + Val(A(19).Text) * Val(B(10).Text) + Val(A(20).Text) * Val(B(16).Text) + Val(A(21).Text) * Val(B(22).Text) + Val(A(22).Text) * Val(B(28).Text) + Val(A(23).Text) * Val(B(34).Text)
an(23).Text = Val(A(18).Text) * Val(B(5).Text) + Val(A(19).Text) * Val(B(11).Text) + Val(A(20).Text) * Val(B(17).Text) + Val(A(21).Text) * Val(B(23).Text) + Val(A(22).Text) * Val(B(29).Text) + Val(A(23).Text) * Val(B(35).Text)

an(24).Text = Val(A(24).Text) * Val(B(0).Text) + Val(A(25).Text) * Val(B(6).Text) + Val(A(26).Text) * Val(B(12).Text) + Val(A(27).Text) * Val(B(18).Text) + Val(A(28).Text) * Val(B(24).Text) + Val(A(29).Text) * Val(B(30).Text)
an(25).Text = Val(A(24).Text) * Val(B(1).Text) + Val(A(25).Text) * Val(B(7).Text) + Val(A(26).Text) * Val(B(13).Text) + Val(A(27).Text) * Val(B(19).Text) + Val(A(28).Text) * Val(B(25).Text) + Val(A(29).Text) * Val(B(31).Text)
an(26).Text = Val(A(24).Text) * Val(B(2).Text) + Val(A(25).Text) * Val(B(8).Text) + Val(A(26).Text) * Val(B(14).Text) + Val(A(27).Text) * Val(B(20).Text) + Val(A(28).Text) * Val(B(26).Text) + Val(A(29).Text) * Val(B(32).Text)
 an(27).Text = Val(A(24).Text) * Val(B(3).Text) + Val(A(25).Text) * Val(B(9).Text) + Val(A(26).Text) * Val(B(15).Text) + Val(A(27).Text) * Val(B(21).Text) + Val(A(28).Text) * Val(B(27).Text) + Val(A(29).Text) * Val(B(33).Text)
 an(28).Text = Val(A(24).Text) * Val(B(4).Text) + Val(A(25).Text) * Val(B(10).Text) + Val(A(26).Text) * Val(B(16).Text) + Val(A(27).Text) * Val(B(22).Text) + Val(A(28).Text) * Val(B(28).Text) + Val(A(29).Text) * Val(B(34).Text)
 an(29).Text = Val(A(24).Text) * Val(B(5).Text) + Val(A(25).Text) * Val(B(11).Text) + Val(A(26).Text) * Val(B(17).Text) + Val(A(27).Text) * Val(B(23).Text) + Val(A(28).Text) * Val(B(29).Text) + Val(A(29).Text) * Val(B(35).Text)

an(30).Text = Val(A(30).Text) * Val(B(0).Text) + Val(A(31).Text) * Val(B(6).Text) + Val(A(32).Text) * Val(B(12).Text) + Val(A(33).Text) * Val(B(18).Text) + Val(A(34).Text) * Val(B(24).Text) + Val(A(35).Text) * Val(B(30).Text)
an(31).Text = Val(A(30).Text) * Val(B(1).Text) + Val(A(31).Text) * Val(B(7).Text) + Val(A(32).Text) * Val(B(13).Text) + Val(A(33).Text) * Val(B(19).Text) + Val(A(34).Text) * Val(B(25).Text) + Val(A(35).Text) * Val(B(31).Text)
an(32).Text = Val(A(30).Text) * Val(B(2).Text) + Val(A(31).Text) * Val(B(8).Text) + Val(A(32).Text) * Val(B(14).Text) + Val(A(33).Text) * Val(B(20).Text) + Val(A(34).Text) * Val(B(26).Text) + Val(A(35).Text) * Val(B(32).Text)
an(33).Text = Val(A(30).Text) * Val(B(3).Text) + Val(A(31).Text) * Val(B(9).Text) + Val(A(32).Text) * Val(B(15).Text) + Val(A(33).Text) * Val(B(21).Text) + Val(A(34).Text) * Val(B(27).Text) + Val(A(35).Text) * Val(B(33).Text)
an(34).Text = Val(A(30).Text) * Val(B(4).Text) + Val(A(31).Text) * Val(B(10).Text) + Val(A(32).Text) * Val(B(16).Text) + Val(A(33).Text) * Val(B(22).Text) + Val(A(34).Text) * Val(B(28).Text) + Val(A(35).Text) * Val(B(34).Text)
an(35).Text = Val(A(30).Text) * Val(B(5).Text) + Val(A(31).Text) * Val(B(11).Text) + Val(A(32).Text) * Val(B(17).Text) + Val(A(33).Text) * Val(B(23).Text) + Val(A(34).Text) * Val(B(29).Text) + Val(A(35).Text) * Val(B(35).Text)
```

Comment: Since you're new to programming, may I ask why you want to work with VB6? I advise you to learn VB.NET. Its syntax is close to VB6, it uses newer technology, and it has more features.(unless of course you have a reason for using VB6).

Answer (score 0):

A Quick sample below, you need to tweak it much more until you end up with 3 loops inside each other.

To create the textboxes first -

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim xText As Integer

    xText = 1

    For xText = 1 To 36
        Load a(xText)
        Load b(xText)
        Load an(xText)

        a(xText).Move a(0).Left, a(xText - 1).Top + 360, a(xText - 1).Width, 285
        a(xText).Visible = True
        a(xText) = a(xText - 1) + 1

        b(xText).Move b(0).Left, b(xText - 1).Top + 360, b(xText - 1).Width, 285
        b(xText).Visible = True
        b(xText) = b(xText - 1) + 1

        an(xText).Move an(0).Left, an(xText - 1).Top + 360, an(xText - 1).Width, 285
        an(xText).Visible = True
    Next xText
End Sub
```

To get the values calculated - ONLY A SAMPLE...

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Dim xSumtotal As Long, xMatrixA As Integer, xMatrixB As Integer

    xSumtotal = 0
    xMatrixA = 0
    xMatrixB = 0

    For xSumtotal = 0 To 35
        If xMatrixA >= 36 Then
            xMatrixA = 0
                Else
            xMatrixA = xMatrixA + 1
        End If

        If xMatrixB >= 36 Then
            xMatrixB = 0
                Else
            xMatrixB = xMatrixB + 6
        End If

        an(xSumtotal) = Val(a(xMatrixA).Text) * Val(b(xMatrixB).Text) + Val(a(xMatrixA + 1).Text) * Val(b(xMatrixB + 6).Text) + Val(a(xMatrixA + 2).Text) * Val(b(xMatrixB + 6).Text) + Val(a(xMatrixA + 3).Text) * Val(b(xMatrixB + 6).Text) + Val(a(xMatrixA + 4).Text) * Val(b(xMatrixB + 6).Text) + Val(a(xMatrixA + 5).Text) * Val(b(xMatrixB + 6).Text)

        ''The if statement will not work as you will get an overflow error because you will be jumping to xMatrixA = 36 on line 6...
        ''You needt to use another 2 FOR/NEXT loops nested inside here to calculate through the 36x36...
        ''Not enough time to make it all work, this will however put you on the right track...    
    Next xSumtotal
End Sub
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Good day sir. Thank you for the code. I tried this code but result is not the same as my code implies. For the whole idea, I will post all the codes to be simplified. Pls help me.

Comment: No problem, if time allows I will gladly assist.